# Start Symbolic Analysis at a Given Address with Angr

Tags: static-analysis, angr

Lets suppose I have a very big binary and I want to reverse just a part of this binary.

Is there a way to tell angr to start symbolic analysis at a given address ?

Answer (score 3):

There sure is.

```
p = angr.Project("target_binary")
state = p.factory.blank_state(addr=0x400770)
```

I strongly recommend reading [the State Presets section of the docs](https://docs.angr.io/core-concepts/states#state-presets) for more information. Crucially, all of the state preset constructors can take the `addr` argument; depending what you're doing, there may be a better preset to use than `blank_state`.

Further resources:

[API docs](http://angr.io/api-doc/angr.html#angr.factory.AngrObjectFactory)

Examples from the angr team that include starting analysis at a specific address:

- [Example 1](https://github.com/angr/angr-doc/blob/master/examples/9447_nobranch/solve.py)
- [Example 2](https://github.com/angr/angr-doc/blob/master/examples/cmu_binary_bomb/solve.py)
- [Example 3](https://github.com/angr/angr-doc/blob/master/examples/defcon2017quals_crackme2000/magic.py)

Comment: Okay thanks is there a way to say to angr i want to get a particular value at a given  memory location ?